# Test one function, with multiple test cases but only use one assert?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have a class method that takes a list and determines if the list is valid or not according to a function.

I want to test it on three lists that are stored as static variables because they are used in other unit tests later on in the code.

```
def test__validate(self):
    decoder = Validator()
    slow_valid = Validator.validate(TestValidator.list_slow)
    med_valid = Validator.validate(TestValidator.list_med)
    fast_valid = Validator.validate(TestValidator.list_fast)


    assert slow_valid == True
    assert med_valid == False
    assert fast_valid == False
```

What is the correct way to remove the multiple assert statements?

Do I defined multiple versions of `test__validate` or are the multiple assert statements okay from a best practices position?

Comment: You may find this useful https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html

Comment: I'm of the opinion that you should have multiple versions of test_validate, e.g., test__validate_slow, test__validate_fast. In this fashion, a failure can be easy isolated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As proposed by @IanShelvington, the best practise for repeated tests with changed input (and result, in your case) is test parametrization. With `pytest`, you could do something like this:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("val_list, result",
                         [(TestValidator.list_slow, True),
                          (TestValidator.list_med, False),
                          (TestValidator.list_fast, False)])

def test_validate(val_list, result):
    assert Validator().validate(val_list) == result
```

This gives you the output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
...
collecting ... collected 3 items

param_result.py::test_validate[val_list0-True] PASSED                    [ 33%]
param_result.py::test_validate[val_list1-False] PASSED                   [ 66%]
param_result.py::test_validate[val_list2-False] PASSED                   [100%]

============================== 3 passed in 0.04s ==============================
```

As you can see, this creates 3 separate tests, with the parameters in the name, so a failing test can easily be identified.

If you want customized names of the shown tests, you can provide them using `ids`:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("val_list, result",
                         [(TestValidator.list_slow, True),
                          (TestValidator.list_med, False),
                          (TestValidator.list_fast, False)],
                         ids=('slow', 'med', 'fast'))
...
```

This would output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
...
param_result.py::test_validate[slow] PASSED                              [ 33%]
param_result.py::test_validate[med] PASSED                               [ 66%]
param_result.py::test_validate[fast] PASSED                              [100%]

============================== 3 passed in 0.06s ==============================
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Python 3.4, You can do this with [subTest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest) in `unittest`.

```
import unittest

class TestValidation(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_validate(self):
        decoder = Validator()
        validation_list = [
            ("slow", Validator.validate(TestValidator.list_slow), True),
            ("med", Validator.validate(TestValidator.list_med), False),
            ("fast", Validator.validate(TestValidator.list_fast), False),
        ]

        for label, actual_output, expected_output in validation_list:
            with self.subTest(label=label):
                self.assertEqual(expected_output, actual_output)
```

The extra `label` field in the three tuples is unnecessary but will make the error much easier to debug in case any of the tests fail. The label text will appear in the `SubTest` error message when any one of the three tests fails, allowing you to diagnose which of the three failed.

Note: I noticed after answering the question was tagged `pytest`. Anyways, `unittest` users may come across and hopefully find this answer helpful.